# import video.js into nuxt.js application not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, video.js

I'm trying to use [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) in a Nuxt app. I ran `yarn add video.js`, which installed video.js and I can see it in `package.json`

In my page `video.vue` I added

```js
import videojs from 'video.js'
```

vscode returns this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'video.js'. '../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/video.js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'video.js';`

I followed the example on the official page for vue: https://videojs.com/guides/vue/

Comment: Have you tried to rerun your development server? It may be if you have multiple lock files.

Comment: yes, still the same.  i've been stuck on this for hours, should be a simple import.

Comment: The error is about types, not a big deal overall, you can probably ignore it. Otherwise, you can always run `npm i -D @types/video.js` as suggested in the error. Should fix the whole thing. But then, maybe you do need to worry about the way you use it, because it's maybe not working on top of that error?

Comment: Feel free to share a public github repo here, if feasible. May speed things up!

Answer (score -1):

To import video.js in Nuxt 3

```
npm install --save-dev video.js
```

Template:

```
<template>
 <v-container>
  <video ref="videoPlayer" width="500" class="video-js"></video>
 </v-container>
</template>
```

script:

```
 <script setup>
  import videojs from "video.js";
  import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css'
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
  const videoPlayer = ref()
  let player = null;
  onMounted(() =>{
    player = videojs(videoPlayer.value, {
      autoplay: false,
      controls: true,
      sources: [
        {
          src: 'video-link',
          type: 'video/mp4'
        }
      ]
    }, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('Player is ready!');
    });
  })
</script>
```